# Adding icons to specific panels in Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kde, gui

When I right click on an application from the menu I see there is an option "add to Panel" however when I click that it goes to the main/default panel.  I want to add icons to a different panel that I added.

I tried adding applications to the main panel and then dragging it to the panel I want it to be in but that didn't work.  I tried adding to desktop and then dragging to the panel but that, too, didn't work.

Comment: is 'lock panels" turned off?

Comment: @ravery do you mean "Lock Widgets"? If so, yes it is turned off.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant. and sorry I don't have more info. just thought I'd throw that out as sometimes the simple things are forgotten

Answer (score 1):

originally I used to edit the config file (`.config/plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`) while KDE was not running - so it doesn't overwrite my changes.

Today I just tried moving an icon from the menu to any panel (while widgets unlocked) and it works (Kubuntu `16.04.3`)!

Though if you need to add a custom icon (e.g. shell script, or `.jar`, ...) or change the app icon then editing the config file is the only way I know right now.